# Why toast displays always 10?

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.setId(i);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String customHtml = "<p>WebView ID: <b>"+i+"</b></p>";
        webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"i: "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        lp.bottomMargin += 5;
        linearLayout.addView(webView, lp);
    }
```

I want to display webview id on toast, but it displays 10 always.

please help to fix this.

Comment: and I suppose you have `int i;` as your class instance variable?

Comment: @marcin_j yes i declared it on class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"i: "+view.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

By the time of click event for loop gets completed and I has the last value that is 10.

or do:

```
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            final int x=i;
            webView = new WebView(this);
            webView.setId(i);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            String customHtml = "<p>WebView ID: <b>"+i+"</b></p>";
            webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
            webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"i: "+x,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            lp.bottomMargin += 5;
            linearLayout.addView(webView, lp);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you use `i` as the `id` of your webviews, the easiest change would be this:

```
Toast.makeText(..., "i: " + view.getId(), ...).show();
```